# how to turn off (or set level) for imported modules' logger?

Tags: python, logging

I have a code which looks like this

```
from others_module import aaa
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
a = aaa()
```

This is the code of others_module.py

```
class aaa():
    def __init__(self):
        logging.warning("some warming")
```

I couldn't seem to turn off the warning from others_module.
What is the way to turn of the warning from my code? 
Channging the code of others_module is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `others_module` is using the `logging.warning` function, which delegates the call to the root logger. You would need to do

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR) # or CRITICAL
```

to prevent `WARNING` events being processed by the root logger.

Code intended to be imported and used as a library shouldn't use the root logger - it should use a package-named logger, as shown in your first code snippet.